# Jade Variables for Links

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I was wondering how to send text to a jade view and use that text to form a link's name and the link its self. I'm not sure what the syntax needs to be.

I've tried:  `a(href=#{link}) #{link}`, what's wrong with that syntax? The current error is Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

full code:

```
extends layout
block content
  h1 #{title}
  p #{text}
  a(href=#{link}) #{linktext}
```

Comment: is there something that doesn't work? what's the question here?

Comment: this doesn't work: a(href=#{link}) #{linktext}. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll have to use this syntax : `!=` to use unescaped buffered code ([check the Jade documentation for more information](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#unescapedbufferedcode))

```
extends layout
block content
  h1 #{title}
  p #{text}
  a(href!=link) #{linktext}
```

Note tested but take a look at the documentation to perfect this.

Edit : As Scimonster said, just using buffered code normally works as expected :

```
  a(href=link) #{linktext}
```

Comment: I believe it should be `a(href=link)`.

Comment: That works thanks! Didn't know about Unescaped Buffered Code.

Comment: @Scimonster They both seem to work. Do you know when one would be preferred over another?

Comment: Actually, i hadn't even realized that `!=` works in attribute setting. `=` is probably safer if you have user-input.